# Find patterns from one file in another file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to find patterns from one file in another file.

The pattern in file one looks something like this:

```
ENSG00000203875.13
ENSG00000262691.1
ENSG00000254911.3
```

File two contains:

```
ENSG00000203875.13 aa aaa bbb cc
ENSG00000227782.2
ENSG00000229582.3
ENSG00000241769.7
ENSG00000245904.4
ENSG00000254823.2
ENSG00000254911.3 cc ccc ccc
ENSG00000260213.6
ENSG00000260997.1
ENSG00000261799.1
ENSG00000262691.1 bbb bbb bbb
ENSG00000267249.1
ENSG00000270012.1
ENSG00000270091.1
ENSG00000270361.1
ENSG00000271533.1
ENSG00000271833.1
ENSG00000271870.1
ENSG00000272379.1
ENSG00000272631.1
ENSG00000273066.5
ENSG00000273855.1
ENSG00000278966.2
ENSG00000279332.1
ENSG00000279407.1
ENSG00000279616.1
ENSG00000279684.1
ENSG00000279835.1
ENSG00000286181.1
ENSG00000286986.1
ENSG00000287817.1
```

I'm trying to find only

```
ENSG00000203875.13 aa aaa bbb cc
ENSG00000254911.3 cc ccc ccc
ENSG00000262691.1 bbb bbb bbb
```

as output. I'm pretty sure `grep -f file_one.txt file_two.txt` should do the job, but instead I just get the content of file_two as output. I don't know what mistake I'm making. Can anyone point it out?

Comment: Add output of `file file_one.txt file_two.txt` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Your `grep` command should work, though if there were a line with a single `.`, then that pattern would match every line in file two.  It's worth trying `grep -Ff` for fixed strings but it's not apparent what the grep issue is from what you've included here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
for i in $(cat file_one.txt); do grep -i $i file_two.txt; done
ENSG00000203875.13 aa aaa bbb cc
ENSG00000262691.1 bbb bbb bbb
ENSG00000254911.3 cc ccc ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an `awk` approach, keeping track of the values of the  first column of *file_one.txt* in array `a`, and then check of the value of the first column of *file_two.txt* is present in the keys of the array:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} $1 in a' file_one.txt file_two.txt
```

Output

```
ENSG00000203875.13 aa aaa bbb cc
ENSG00000254911.3 cc ccc ccc
ENSG00000262691.1 bbb bbb bbb
```

Another option using grep:

```
grep -f file_one.txt file_two.txt
```